# RegEx: Determine if inputstring is expression or call of formula

Tags: regex, delphi

I've asked a few questions about RegEx Delphi on this site. So far I've been helped quite well. So far I've been quite successful but I have some problems with some regular expressions.

Anyways, that being said;

**My problem**

User can input a expression, for example:

```
[x]=[Fib(5)]+[Fib(10)];
```

In the example above, [x] is an variable. [Fib(5)] is a call of the Fib function with parameter 5 (constant). After some parse processes; the remaining inputstring is:

```
[Fib(5)]+[Fib(10)]
```

I want this to be an expression (ofcourse, because there is a operator in the middle of the 2 formulacalls). I distinguish an expression by searching for operators in the main expression (in this case: +), and by checking that the inputstring is not an formula (because there can be operators in the formulacall parameters).

I check for an formula with this regular expression:

```
^\[\w+\([a-zA-Z0-9()[\]+\-*\/ANDOR><≠≥≤==]+\)\]$
```

This regex is my latest version in an attempt to make it work.
What i try to achieve is the following:

```
[Fib(5)]+[Fib(10)] //Match on Expression, No Match on Formulacall
[Fib(5)] // Match on FormulaCall, No match on Expression
```

The Regular Expression above for matching formula calls does currently match on

```
[Fib(5)]+[Fib(10)]
```

**My question**

How can I make sure that my regex for matching formulacalls stops after the call is closed, and does not match a complete expression? I get why it matches the whole expression, but I can't find a way to make it stop. If the string does not contain 1 and only 1 formula call, but does contain one or more operators, it should not match.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have both begin and end of string markers there (`^` and `$`). I am not a regex expert, but ISTM that can only match the entire string or nothing, so your non-greedy marker (`?`) won't help. Can't you remove these?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, you are right. I removed it a few minutes after I created topic, but forgot to edit my openingspost. Thanks!